# Linux shell script for brightness of all monitors

Tags: shell, syntax-error

I have found a script to set the brightness of all monitors at once which works using it with one option but not with another option.

The script is (Below Best Answer):
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-control-monitor-brightness-with-keyboard-shortcut/

```
b=$(xrandr --current --verbose | grep Brightness)
b=${b#*: }                      # Remove "Brightness: "
b=${b#0.}                       # 0.30 --> 30
[[ $b == "1.0" ]] && b="100"
case $1 in
    +*|-*)
        b=$((b $1))             # LINE 19 b=b+10,  b=b-10
        ;;
    [0-9]*)   # LINE 21
        b=$1                    # b=75
        ;;
    *) # LINE 24
        echo $b; exit
        ;;
esac
```

So it works if I do:

```
brightness 90
```

But not if I try to increase or decrease the current brightness:

```
    brightness +10
    /usr/local/bin/brightness: line 19: 90
    Brightness: 0.90: syntax error in expression (error token is "Brightness: 0.90")
/usr/local/bin/brightness: line 21: [[: 90
    Brightness: 0.90: syntax error in expression (error token is "Brightness: 0.90")
/usr/local/bin/brightness: line 22: [[: 90
    Brightness: 0.90: syntax error in expression (error token is "Brightness: 0.90")
/usr/local/bin/brightness: line 24: [[: 90
    Brightness: 0.90: syntax error in expression (error token is "Brightness: 0.90")
xrandr: unrecognized option 'Brightness:'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
xrandr: unrecognized option 'Brightness:'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

Any idea?

Comment: `Any idea?` Patch the script and fix the issue. [Debug the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script) and find what's wrong. What exactly do you have in mind with "any idea"? It's nice for stackoverflow question to be self contained - please include the script sources into the question. Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: run it under `-x` (change shebang line to `#!/bin/bash -x`) and show the output

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. It offers no information at all. All SO questions are about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `program` or `code`